# JavaScript object value based on variable

Tags: javascript, object

I have a variable named day. It contains the current day (i.e. "Wednesday") as a string. I also have an object called data. When I alert data.Wednesday it gives me the total count for that day.

```
alert(data.Wednesday); //alerts 2
```

I want the count for the current day (not the hard-coded Wednesday). My question is, how do I replace `data.Wednesday` with `data.day`. I obviously cant do `data.day` because day isn't an element of the data object. Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ugh, wrong duplicate. This is the correct one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/218196. Someone else please close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access the property by using squared brackets.

```
var day = "Wednesday";
alert(data[day]);
```

Answer (score 2):

To let JS evaluate your expression and lookup a property with the value use square bracket notation

```
var data = {someValue: 'Wednesday'};
var day = 'someValue';
data[day]; // 'Wednesday'
```

Where someValue can be a string or a number.